# In java JDBC connection error ORA-28000: the account got locked, but db account is not locked

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I could connect to Oracle XE, DB from console using the credentials (Username: HR, Password : *****). But I'm getting the error message

> ORA-28000: the account got locked

when I try to establish connection from java program using JDBC.

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"USER NAME","PASSWORD");
          Statement statement = con.createStatement();  
          ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select 'Connected' from dual");  

          while (resultset.next()) {
                 System.out.println(resultset.getString(1));
          }        
          statement.close();  
          con.close();  
   }
```

How to connect to DB from this java program?

Answer (score 0):

When connect using the credentials (Username : system, Password : ####) the account got connected without any issue from java program.
However, when connected using the credentials (Username: HR, Password : ****) got the error message ORA-28000: the account got locked. But was able to login using these HR credentials from oracle console.
So, to get the connection from java program, did the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

          String query;

          // Connect to system Database first
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"system","####");
          Statement statement = con.createStatement();  
          query = "alter user HR identified by HR account unlock";

          //Unlock the account
          ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

          //Connect to HR database
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","HR","****");
          statement = con.createStatement();  

          //Fetch all the tables in HR database
          query = "select 'Connected' from dual";
          resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

          //Prints records fetched
          while (resultset.next()) {
                 System.out.println(resultset.getString(1));
          }        

          statement.close();  
          con.close();  

   }
```

The HR account got unlocked and now able to execute other queries without issues :)

Comment: it might be smarter to find why the account got locked. This mechanism is there for a reason. Password aging is one of them.

Comment: yes, this is just a quick work around, sure to work for this scenario.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the username to "System" instead of "HR". and that it! you will be able now to connect to your database.

Comment: SYSTEM user account is not meant for end users. Never use system to login, other than maintenance tasks. So this is not a good advice.